# cannot print from evince any more

Tags: 20.04, printing, hp, pdf, evince

I'm on 20.04 with a HP Jaserjet 1018, hplip version 3.20.3

Since today, I cannot print PDFs from Evince (Document Viewer) any more. In the "Status" tab of the HP Device Manager, it says "the print job has completed" after a while, but nothing happens. In the "Job Queue" Section of the "Printer Control Tab", the "Status" is "Printing" at first, and then switches to "Stopped". Some observations:

- This also happens with PDFs that printed just fine this way
  yesterday.
- The same happens when I try to print a TIFF from evince.
- Printing PDFs from Firefox works just fine, including the ones that won't print from Evince.
- Printing PDFs from Okular also works fine, including reversed-order and odd-pages-only
- Printing a PNG from Geeqie also works fine.
- As far as I remember, I did not run any updates yesterday.
- The only thing I remember doing differently today is that I tried to print only odd pages in backwards order the first time I tried printing today. But it also happens when I print with default settings.

I already have restarted both printer and PC (in this order). I have no idea what else I could try. Any ideas?

Comment: *The only thing I remember doing differently today is that I tried to print only odd pages in backwards order the first time I tried printing today.* Have you tried resetting to the default options?

Comment: Yes, I did (and I just double-checked to be certain). Reverting to printing "all pages" and "all sheets" does not help. Thanks though: clarified that above.